# Select columns in a cycle in R

Tags: r, select

I try create a set of tables (answer data frame), using cycle:

```
for (col in 1:ncol(answers)){
 table(subset(answers,answers[,col]>6,select=answers[,col]),subset(answers,answers[,col]>6,select=c(clu)))
}
```

But I have an error:

```
Error in sort.list(y) : 'x' for 'sort.list' must be atomic.
```

What is wrong in my code? Can I use column names instead of indexes?
Thank you!

Comment: Please add what you are *trying to do* to your question. The use of `table` and `subset` looks like it could be improved substantially into something more *R-like*.

Comment: Thank you for reply,
I try to make a set of contingency tables for my dataset, but have a low frequences for part of column values, so I try filter it out. The problem is treshold (now it equal to 6) will be differ for each table.

Answer (score 0):

A pattern like this is much more R-like:

```
lapply(answers, table, answers$clu)
```

see for example this code which uses a builtin dataset:

```
lapply(cars, table, cars$dist)
```

`lapply` performs the function on each of the columns, which you can use to run `table` on each of the columns. So the code example above runs `table(cars$a_column, cars$dist)` for each column in the `cars` dataset.